# Seeking shapefiles on publicly owned land in UK?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

Where can I find shapefiles of land owned by the National Health Service (NHS), Local authorities, universities and Ministry of Defence (MOD)?

Comment: If you are a student then try Edina digimap.

Comment: openstreetmap.org is always my first "go to"